# Pass subsets of datatable to SQL Server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to figure out how I could breakup my datatable and send that (as UDT) down to sql server).  So if I have 100,000 in my datatable I would like to be able to break it up into 10,000 chunks to send down to my sql server.  I am just not sure about how I would take the datatable with 100,000 and break it up into those 10,000k blocks?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

So if I used something like this:

```
var results = (from myRow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
              select myRow).take(10000);
```

Not sure how I could ensure I grabbed the next set of 10,000 rows from the datatable and ensure I don't send duplicates and get all of the rows?

Comment: @BrokenGlass can you further explain what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write yourself a simple method to turn any collection into chunks of a specified size:

```
/// <summary>Splits a collection into chunks of equal size. The last chunk may be smaller than chunkSize, but all chunks, if any, will contain at least one element.</summary>
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
{
    if (chunkSize <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("chunkSize must be greater than zero.", "chunkSize");
    return chunkIterator(source, chunkSize);
}
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> chunkIterator<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    foreach (var elem in source)
    {
        list.Add(elem);
        if (list.Count == chunkSize)
        {
            yield return list;
            list = new List<T>();
        }
    }
    if (list.Count > 0)
        yield return list;
}
```

And then you can trivially use this, for example:

```
foreach (var chunk in myDataTable.AsEnumerable().Chunk(10000))
{
    // Process the chunk
}
```